# Google Sheets Formula to validate for row wise entries dynamically

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having a table in a requirement document which has mandatory columns to be filled

[image]

If any of the mandatory entries is missed the validation for the whole range should say not ok.
For Example if A2 is not filled and  C2, D2 and E2 are filled the validation should say not ok.

I tried `Array formula` and `ifs` to check for all combinations across the range, but its to overwhelming.

Any easy way to do this, please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=If(and(ARRAYFORMULA (A2:F2 <> "")),"It's OK,"It's not OK")
```

If you need it to be for the whole range no matter the row, change A2:F2 with the whole range

Or, if you need the whole range by row (use your range instead of A2:F6):

```
=BYROW(A2:F6,lambda(each,If(and(ARRAYFORMULA (each <> "")),"It's OK,"It's not OK")))
```